# Generate pdf from HTML string with styles net core blazor

Tags: printing, blazor, html-to-pdf, page-numbering, printjs

Currently, I have an HTML string to generate the PDF. The number of pages will vary according to the data which will be added to this HTML string.

**Note: this HTML is a complete HTML string not div or p tags**

I need to print the number of pages in the footer of every page (example Page 1 of 10).

Currently, I am using https://github.com/Append-IT/Blazor.Printing but it does not support this kind of scenario.

Please recommend a good .net core library free if possible or economically paid library